# How to include a JavaScript function call as a parameter on another JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

How can I have a parameter to one JS function be Function Name with parameters to call another function?

something like:

```
onClick="Clicked(this, 'SomeFunction('test')'"
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span onclick="Clicked(this, 'SomeFunc', ['test', 123])">AAAA</span>

...

function Clicked(thisObject, funcName, params)
{
 // find an object with name funcName in default (window) scope
 var func = window[funcName];

 // test that the object exist and that it's a function
 if (func && typeof func == "function")
 {
  // call the function with passed params
  // passing 'thisObject' enables to use 'this' keyword within the called function
  func.apply(thisObject, params);

  // as an alternative you may call it without 'this' object
  func.apply(null, params);
 }
}

function SomeFunc(text, num)
{
    alert("text: " + text + ", number: " + num);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
onClick = "Clicked(this, function () {SomeFunction('test')});"


function Clicked (obj, functionToFire)
{
   functionToFire();
}
```

Comment: ok inside of the Clicked function how do I call the SomeFunction using the var passed to Clicked function?

Comment: @OutOFTouch Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Assuming SomeFunction already exists, this will call it right and not create an anonymous function? I am getting an exception ; is missing, do I need to add a semicolon just before the closing }?

Comment: @OutOFTouch Can you post your code around that? You don't "need" to add a semi colon, but it is good practice.

Comment: I am generating this script from server code, I accidentally included an extra open paren, removed that and it doesn't throw any errors. I was just trying to get the syntax correct now I will try calling the method from the other method like you showed above.

Comment: Your answer works, but I went with Kamarey's answer since I also want to validate that the function exists before calling it. I am not sure which answer to mark as the answer?

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Kamarey for the help and everyone else too.

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers correct as I need to also use Kevins answer, Kevin can I do this myButton.click = functionToFire(); ?

Comment: All you need is `onClick = "function() { someFunction('test') }"`. This passes an anonymous function that, when invoked on a click, invokes your function with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function doSomeWork(arg1, arg2)
{
    arg2();
}
function displayThis(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
doSomeWork("11",function(){ displayThis("123");});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you meant to pass arg1 to arg2 like: `arg2(arg1);`

Answer (score -1):

What you have would work, although, you'd need to use the javascript eval function to evaluate the value once in the function:

```
function Clicked(obj, functionText)
{
   // do something with object....
   eval(functionText);
}
```

Otherwise, if there's no parameter, you can always pass the function itself:

```
onClick="Clicked(this, SomeFunction)"
```

and implement like this:

```
function Clicked(obj, func)
{
    // do something with object...
    func();
}
```

Comment: Note that it would be very amateurish to use `eval` for something like this.  `eval` has it's use(s?), this isn't one of them.

Answer (score -1):

This couldn't be simpler:

```
onClick = "function() { someFunction('test') }"
```